# comparing a single value against an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CHECKas()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim lastcol As Long
    Dim l As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rname As Constants
    Set rngTarg = Selection
    lastrow = Sheets("report").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    lastcol = Sheets("report").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Sheets("FEBBRAIO").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).Copy
    Sheets("REPORT").Select
    Cells(1, lastcol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    rname = Application.ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    For i = 2 To lastrow
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("report").Select
        If Range("f2:f" & lastrow) <= Val(CStr(rname.Value)) _
            And Range("g2:g" & lastrow) > Val(CStr(rname.Value)) Then

            Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "1"

        Else

            Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = 0

        End If

    Next i
End Sub
```

I'm new in VBA and I can't understand how to compare a constant value with each cell in a `range("g2:g" & lastrow)` and `("f2:f" & lastrow)`. The constant value is an active cell in my case. For example considering this formula: `IF(AND($R$1<G2;$R$1>=f2);1;0` where `R$1$` is the active cell of the last not empty column in ROW 1. I need to fill the entire column (that is `activecell.column`) with the output coming out form this formula.

But the I Got mismatch error in:

```
If Range("f2:f" & lastrow) <= Val(CStr(rname.Value)) _
    And Range("g2:g" & lastrow) > Val(CStr(rname.Value)) Then
    Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = "1"
Else
    Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column).Value = 0
End If
```

I know from the previous question that this error occurs because I'm trying to comparing a single value against an array of values. How can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
Range("F" & i)
```

in your code. Same thing applies to other instances of such code.